# Lua C API - Assign and use object member of a class from C++

Tags: c++, lua, lua-api

I'm trying to instantiate and use object of Lua classes from C++. 
Lua class is defined like this.

```
myclass = {}

function myclass:new(o)
   o=o or {}
   setmetatable(o,self)
   self.__index=self
   return o
end

function myclass:init()
   self.something = 0
end

function myclass:perform()
   self.something = self.something + 0.5
   return performsomething(self.something)
end
```

To instantiate object in C++, I do the following :

```
lua_getglobal(L,"myclass");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "new");
lua_pcall(L,0,1,0);
lua_newtable(L);
lua_setglobal(L, "objname");
```

Then to initialize :

```
lua_getglobal(L,"myclass");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "init");
lua_getglobal(L,"objname");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
```

And then to perform :

```
lua_getglobal(L, "myclass");
lua_getfield(L, -1, "perform");
lua_getglobal(L, "objname");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0);
double res = lua_tonumber(-1);
```

For this example, I didn't include the `lua_pop()` methods I use when needed.

It appears that, with prints, I could get the following informations. Lua object is successfully instantiated with new method. It is also successfully initialized in init method. But, when calling perform method, `self.something` member doesn't change, its value is stucked  to 0, which seems to mean I'm not calling the object member method.
I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the way I manage Lua stack to access object member function.

Did anyone already worked with a similar case and could help here ? 
Thanks
Bests

Comment: I'm not sure how I am supposed to do that.

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was wrong.  `lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0);` means that there are 0 arguments, but you've pushed the object `lua_getglobal(L, "objname");` as the first argument, so you should use `lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);`

Comment: Also, you're ignoring the result of `myclass:new()`, and instead saving new empty table under name `objname`. Remove that `lua_newtable(L)` after the call to `myclass` constructor.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think this is true for init and perform (I fixed this now) methods since I actually pass the objname as the self argument. But are you sure new method is supposed to receive an argument, since I only assign its return value to objname global ?

Comment: @Vlad I did that, and then in perform method self.something is equal to nil. I think there is still an instantiation issue here.

Comment: @Philiste - `But are you sure new method is supposed to receive an argument` Yes, of course!  The `new` method does use this argument inside its body. You need to pass `lua_getglobal(L,"myclass");` as the argument.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When calling this kind of new method inside pure lua code, a call without argument returns a new object. It's determined inside function at the first line, o=o or {}, where it checks if input value is nil or not. So I was assuming that no input is determined as nil, then it outputs a new table object. But I might be wrong ?

Comment: @Philiste - Yes, no input means `nil`.  But `o` is the second parameter.  The first parameter is `self`, and it must be non-nil.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you didn't fix the `nargs` argument to `lua_pcall` function.

When the function is defined with colon syntax (`class:func()`) you have to explicitly pass the `self` argument from the C/C++ side. There's nothing like that in your example.

Minimally changing your code, it would look like this:

Lua side:

```
function performsomething(x)
    print("type:", type(x))
    print("value:", x)
    return x
end

myclass = {}

function myclass:new(o)
   o=o or {}
   setmetatable(o,self)
   self.__index=self
   return o
end

function myclass:init()
   self.something = 0
end

function myclass:perform()
   self.something = self.something + 0.5
   return performsomething(self.something)
end
```

C/C++ side:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main()
{
    lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    luaL_dofile(L, "myclass.lua");

    // instantiate
    lua_getglobal(L,"myclass");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "new");
    lua_getglobal(L, "myclass");
    lua_pcall(L,1,1,0);
    lua_setglobal(L, "objname");

    // init
    lua_getglobal(L,"myclass");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "init");
    lua_getglobal(L,"objname");
    lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);

    // perform
    lua_getglobal(L, "myclass");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "perform");
    lua_getglobal(L, "objname");
    lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);

    double res = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    printf("Result: %f\n", res);

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following examples, I created a simple class in C++ that can be used in Lua using the Lua C API. Having completed it, I imagine much of it extends beyond the scope of your question; however, I hope my explanations and examples help.

When I am using Lua's C API to create `userdata`, this is how I typically write my `main` function in C++. In this case, `MyClass.h` is the header file for the simple class I wrote for this example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "MyClass.h"
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Check to make sure you have at least one .lua input file.
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Filename(s) expected from command line" << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Try-catch block to handle any errors encountered when executing the Lua file(s).
    try {
        lua_State* L = luaL_newstate(L);
        luaL_openlibs(L);
        // Call a function to register Lua methods for `MyClass`; its declaration and definition are below.
        lua_MyClass_register(L);
        for (char** cpp = argv + 1; cpp < argv + argc; ++cpp) {
            // Run the Lua script--provided as a command-line arg--and handle errors.
            if (luaL_dofile(L, *cpp)) {
                const char* err = lua_tostring(L, -1);
                lua_close(L);
                throw std::runtime_error(err);
            }
        }
        lua_close(L);
    } catch (const std::runtime_error &err) {
        // Catch fatal errors from the Lua script and exit.
        std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now for the file `MyClass.h`, which contains the declarations for my simple example class:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
#define LUA_MYCLASS "MyClass"
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

// Class declaration.
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int something_in);
    ~MyClass();
    // Setter function to change the value of `something`.
    void set(int something_in);
    // Getter function to return `something`.
    const int & get() const;
private:
    int something;
};

// The following declarations are for the C functions that correspond to `MyClass`'s member function.
int lua_MyClass_new(lua_State* L);
int lua_MyClass_delete(lua_State* L);
int lua_MyClass_get(lua_State* L);
int lua_MyClass_set(lua_State* L);
int lua_MyClass_newindex(lua_state* L);
int lua_MyClass_table_newindex(lua_State* L);
void lua_MyClass_register(lua_State* L);

// `luaL_Reg` is a struct provided in one of the Lua header files used to register userdata methods.
// This one is for the class methods.
static const luaL_Reg MyClass_methods[] = {
    {"set", lua_MyClass_set},
    {"get", lua_MyClass_get},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

// This one is for the class metamethods.
static const luaL_Reg MyClass_metamethods[] = {
    {"__gc", lua_MyClass_delete},
    {"__newindex", lua_MyClass_newindex},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

#endif
```

Here is `MyClass.h`'s corresponding `.cpp` file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

// These are the class member function definitions.
MyClass::MyClass(int something_in) {
    something = something_in;
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {

}

void MyClass::set(int something_in) {
    something = something_in;
    return;
}

const int & MyClass::get() const {
    return something;
}

// These are the definitions for the C functions that Lua will use to call the member functions.
// `MyClass` constructor, which corresponds to `MyClass.new` in Lua.
int lua_MyClass_new(lua_State* L) {
    // Optional argument to supply to the `MyClass` constructor; using `luaL_optinteger`, it defaults to 0.
    int something_in = static_cast<int>(luaL_optinteger(L, 1, 0));
    MyClass** mcpp = reinterpret_cast<MyClass**>(lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(MyClass**)));
    *mcpp = new MyClass(something_in);
    luaL_setmetatable(L, LUA_MYCLASS);
    return 1;
}

// `MyClass` destructor, which corresponds to the `__gc` metamethod in Lua.
int lua_MyClass_delete(lua_State* L) {
    MyClass* mcp = *reinterpret_cast<MyClass**>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_MYCLASS));
    delete mcp;
    return 0;
}

// C function corresponding to `MyClass::set`.
int lua_MyClass_set(lua_State* L) {
    MyClass* mcp = *reinterpret_cast<MyClass**>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_MYCLASS));
    int something_in = static_cast<int>(luaL_checkinteger(L, 2));
    mcp->set(something_in);
    return 0;
}

// C function corresponding to `MyClass::get`.
int lua_MyClass_get(lua_State* L) {
    MyClass* mcp = *reinterpret_cast<MyClass**>(luaL_checkudata(L, 1, LUA_MYCLASS));
    lua_pushinteger(L, mcp->get());
    return 1;
}

// `__newindex` metamethod for `MyClass` userdata that prevents any members from being added.
int lua_MyClass_newindex(lua_State* L) {
    return luaL_error(L, "attempt to modify a read-only object");
}

// `__newindex` metamethod for the `MyClass` table that prevents any methods from being added--I will explain more below.
int lua_MyClass_table_newindex(lua_State* L) {
    return luaL_error(L, "attempt to modify a read-only table");
}

// Function to register all the above functions for use in Lua; this gets called in `main.cpp`.
void lua_MyClass_register(lua_State* L) {
    // Create a global table that will contain all the `MyClass` methods as functions.
    // Include `lua_MyClass_new` as a constructor in the form `MyClass.new`.
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, lua_MyClass_new);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "new");
    // Include `MyClass::get` and `MyClass::set` in this table as well.
    luaL_setfuncs(L, MyClass_methods, 0);

    // Create a metatable for the global table `MyClass`--which was just created.
    lua_newtable(L);
    // Prevent access to the metatable.
    lua_pushliteral(L, "metatable");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__metatable");
    lua_pushcfunction(L, lua_MyClass_table_newindex);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__newindex");
    // Set this second table as the metatable for the one created above.
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    // Call the first table "MyClass" and add it to the global environment table (_ENV).
    lua_setglobal(L, LUA_MYCLASS);

    // Create a metatable to be used by `MyClass` objects--this is different from the above tables because it will not contain the `new` method.
    luaL_newmetatable(L, LUA_MYCLASS);
    // Same as before, lock the metatable.
    lua_pushliteral(L, "metatable");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__metatable");
    // Add metamethods contained in the `luaL_Reg` struct `MyClass_metamethods`.
    luaL_setfuncs(L, MyClass_metamethods, 0);

    // Create an index--the `__index` metamethod--for the above table to use for `MyClass` objects.
    lua_newtable(L);
    // Add methods.
    luaL_setfuncs(L, MyClass_methods, 0);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
    // This pop operation is probably unnecessary since the Lua stack should be cleaned up when this function returns.
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    return;
}
```

Lastly, here is my input Lua file, `test.lua`:

```
-- `MyClass` constructor with no arguments; `something` will be set to 0.
m1 = MyClass.new()
print(m1:get())

-- `MyClass` constructor with an argument; `something` will be set to 5.
m2 = MyClass.new(5)
print(m2:get())

-- Use the `set` method to change the value of `something` to 6.
m2:set(6)
print(m2:get())
```

This will output the following:

```
0
5
6
```

The definition of the function `lua_MyClass_register` is quite complicated and involves the creation of many tables. I wrote it the way I did because I wanted to create a global table containing the `MyClass` constructor and methods in the same form as, say, the global `string` table in Lua. Take the function `string.match`, for instance: it can be called as a function, as with `string.match(str, pattern)`; or, it can be called as a method, as with `str:match(pattern)`. The way I registered all the functions for `MyClass` allows for this behavior, except that the global table `MyClass` also contains a constructor, whereas objects of type `MyClass` do not.